# How to configure npm and set up private registry?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm from the java world and my company is giving node.js a try. I've several questions about packaging and deploying node.js and I apologize if these questions sound like its coming from someone institutionalized by the java way of doing things. I managed to create a toy node application that uses websockets and HTTP on my CentOS dev box. I installed npm and node using yum. I didn't have to configure anything so there must be some npm repository configured by default.

Where in npm is this repository configured? Is it some config file, and if so can I change the defaults?

Can I create a private repository to host proprietary node modules for use of engineers within my company? 
Does node have an equivalent of a jar file for archiving and storing it in a repository?

Is there a open source jfrog artifactory like third party product to host a private npm repository?

How do I install nodejs applications in a customer's production environment that doesn't have access to public internet?